# JSF h:outputLabel for : Cannot resolve symbol 'username'

Tags: jsf

В документе xhtml идея выделяет как Cannot resolve symbol мой 'username' выделив красным в коде. Привожу отрывок xhtml с куском где возникает ошибка. 
Строка

```
<h:outputLabel for="username" class="control-label col-sm-4">User Name:</h:outputLabel>
```

сам код

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://primefaces.org/ui ">

<h:head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Conpatible"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <title>JSF CRUD Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .btnWidth {
            width: 80px;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="createStudentForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Create Student Record</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" class="control-label col-sm-4">User Name:</h:outputLabel>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h:inputText id="name-id" value="#{studentBean.name}" class="form-control"
                             validatorMessage="User name is required">
                    <f:validateRequired/>
                </h:inputText>
            </div>
        </div>
```

в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: На странице нет компонента с `id` = `username`. в `for` указывается `id` компонента, для которого предназначен этот лэйбл.

Comment: т.е. если ниже у меня объявлена конструкция с <h:inputText id="name-id" то и в for я должен указать эту name-id. h:outputLabel for="name-id."?

Comment: Да .Так. for="name-id"